# In Google App Script, what code would I need to authorize an API?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

**Question**:
Can I add the authorization part of my google sheets add-on into my add-on's code or does it need to be a separate thing? What would that code look like? If adding the authorization process into the google app script isn't an option, what would be the next best option and what would that look like?

**Premise**:
I'm *very* new to coding or working with an API, google app script, and google cloud platform. I have looked over Google's documentation a dozen times and I'm still unsure how to actually implement the authorization process. Using the HTTP/REST option looks like the best option but I'm really not sure. I've gotten the clientID, secret, URI, etc... that would be required but I don't know where I put that information. Does the code need to be on my website? If so, what would that look like or where can I go to learn more about it?

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Authorization will be taken care of automatically by Google. https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

### Approach

When using Apps Script you won't need to insert your credentials anywhere. The Auth flow is managed by the Apps Script environment. Every time you will need extra permissions to run your script, the environment will prompt for your authorization. This will generally require a normal login to the google account you want to use to authorize your script.

Using Google APIs on Apps Script can be done using two different patterns:

#### Pattern 1: Built-in Google Services

You can use the Apps Script scaffold G Suite Apps classes to work on G Suite Documents, Sheets, Forms, Slides and more. This will feel like programming with native classes and interfaces than using an over-the-internet API.

#### Pattern 2: Advanced Google Services

Advanced services are essentially thin wrappers around the Google APIs. They You must enable an advanced service before you can use it in a script. To enable the Advanced Services visit the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

### References:

[Built-in Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services)

[Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)